# What is the process that companies do to hire graduates?

Tags: recruitment

Say for example 1000 people apply for 1 graduate position on a companies website. I find it unlikely that they are going to read everyone's resumes or am I wrong? 
What steps do they do to filter out the applicants to finally get the 1 successful applicant?

Comment: VTC too broad, every industry is different and there can be wild variations between companies.

Comment: You will likely need to do some external research before asking a more specific question here. You are correct that many companies use filtering software, but most of that is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Randomize the applicants, then reject the first n/e applicants, then take the best one after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally they have automated screening that removes anyone not meeting a particular set of criteria. Be use to use the key words in the job ad and make sure to exactly follow any directions they give for submission as people who don;t follow direction are generally immediately filtered out.

The resumes left after that are often reviewed by an HR person who further screens out people considered less qualified, then those resumes left go to the hiring manager(s) who determines who to interview.

And for the record, yes I did review well over a 1000 resumes one time when we were hiring more than 100 new people.  We even interviewed several hundred. So yes the resume may get reviewed even when there are a lot of them or it might be mostly handled by an automated system.